# Packaging an eclipse project to a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I'm looking to package an eclipse project I made to a jar file. I made a simple health monitoring application using the window builder and java beans. I know I have to create a manifest.txt file and do something with the palette in the builder but I'm lost. Quite new to this any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Trying using Maven to build it for you.. Maven is a build tool to help developers do things like this. First we need to convert your project to use maven:

**Step 1 -**
Right click your project, and go to Configure->Convert to Maven. When the window appears press okay and wait.

**Step 2-**
Now right click your project and go to Run As -> Maven Build

This will now build a .JAR inside your build path under the target folder.

Maven is a very powerful tool and has many benfits.

source: http://maven.apache.org/guides/